# Want to automate repetitive process in python

Tags: python, automation

I have below a process for downloading api data.This is fine and does the job although I am fairly new to programming and feel like there is a much cleaner way to do this rather than repeating the code 4 times.Any help on how to automate this to avoid the repetitive code?

```
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': 'abc'}
_api_token = 'api key'
 r1 = requests.get('website',workspace_id=xyz&since=2017-01-01&until=2017-12-31&user_agent=abc,auth= 
 (_api_token, 'api_token'),headers=headers)

r2 = requests.get('website',workspace_id=xyz&since=2018-01-01&until=2018-12-31&user_agent=abc,auth= 
 (_api_token, 'api_token'),headers=headers)

r3 = requests.get('website',workspace_id=xyz&since=2019-01-01&until=2019-12-31&user_agent=abc,auth= 
 (_api_token, 'api_token'),headers=headers)

r4 = requests.get('website',workspace_id=xyz&since=2020-01-01&until=2020-05-05&user_agent=abc,auth= 
 (_api_token, 'api_token'),headers=headers)

     x1 = r1.json()
     x2 = r2.json()
     x3 = r3.json()
     x4 = r4.json()
     x1.keys()
     import pandas as pd
     df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1['data'])
     df2 = pd.DataFrame(x2['data'])
     df3 = pd.DataFrame(x3['data'])
     df4 = pd.DataFrame(x4['data'])
```

Attach python [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Ol0.png)

Comment: What's `r1`, `r2` etc? And how do you set them up. Because yes, you could combine all these into one loop that iterates over your (presumably) four URL's instead of hardcoding it. But to be honest, this is more a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. If you feel that this is wrong, poke a comment and I'll retract the close vote :)

Comment: Belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what does x1.keys() do? If calling .keys() and having the intermediate x1-4 isn't necessary, r1 to r4 can be stored on an arraysi it's simple mapping by calling the json() and pd.DataFrame on ['data'], but otherwise you will need to specify what's actually going on

Comment: @Torxed Updated my code.Please check it. r1,r2,r3,r4 all are data fetch from API for different year. problem is that API fetch for 1 year data only. Can we automate this process.

Comment: @ Martheen Updated my code.Please check it. r1,r2,r3,r4 all are data fetch from API for different year. problem is that API fetch for 1 year data only. Can we automate this process? Code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a code review/enhancement question as I pointed out in the questions. So I would probably ask these types of questions there in the future.

However, as I see these popping up every now and then I figured I'd share how you should (probably) think when in these situations. So the first thing you want to do is use your human super power to find patterns. We humans are (so far) pretty good at spotting patterns in large data collections. In your case, the obvious ones are:

[image]

(I converted your pseudo code into something more realistic, again, post your real code and mask just the important things. The GET Query fields for instance shouldn't have been masked where as the key/token should. I omitted fixing your date patters that wouldn't work as they highlighted better in color this way to emphasis the pattern seen).

Here's a minimal working example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent': 'abc'}
_api_token = 'api key'

r1 = requests.get('http://url/json.php',
                    params={"workspace_id" : "xyz", "since" : "2017-01-01", "until" : "2017-12-31"},
                    auth= (_api_token, 'api_token'),
                    headers=headers)

r2 = requests.get('http://url/json.php',
                    params={"workspace_id" : "xyz", "since" : "2018-01-01", "until" : "2018-12-31"}, 
                    auth= (_api_token, 'api_token'),
                    headers=headers)

r3 = requests.get('http://url/json.php',
                    params={"workspace_id" : "xyz", "since" : "2019-01-01", "until" : "2019-12-31"},
                    auth=(_api_token, 'api_token'),
                    headers=headers)

r4 = requests.get('http://url/json.php',
                    params={"workspace_id" : "xyz", "since" : "2020-01-01", "until" : "2020-05-05"},
                    auth= (_api_token, 'api_token'),
                    headers=headers)

x1 = r1.json()
x2 = r2.json()
x3 = r3.json()
x4 = r4.json()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1['data'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x2['data'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(x3['data'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(x4['data'])
```

Now to reduce this, we'll tacke each pattern first. This is because, most of the time tackling the whole issue will be to complicated - so we reduce the task into smaller workloads.

So, pattern one can be reduced to:

```py
def get_data(since, until):
    return = requests.get('http://url/json.php',
                    params={"workspace_id" : "xyz", "since" : since, "until" : until},
                    auth= (_api_token, 'api_token'),
                    headers=headers)

dates = [
    {"since" : "2017-01-01", "until" : "2017-12-31"},
    {"since" : "2018-01-01", "until" : "2018-12-31"},
    {"since" : "2019-01-01", "until" : "2019-12-31"},
    {"since" : "2020-01-01", "until" : "2020-05-05"}
]

for date_pair_dict in dates:
    r = get_data(**date_pair_dict) # We can use dictionary->parameter expansion this way
                                   # which equals doing get_data(since=date_pair_dict['since'], ...)
```

This reduction isn't extremely big, but it already solves/hints what we'll do next.
Which is to incorporate pattern 2 and 3 into this new syntax and use the fact that we're already looping over `since` and `until` and there for can work with the data instead of store it and then work on it.

This would boil down to:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent': 'abc'}
_api_token = 'api key'

def get_data(since, until):
    return = requests.get('http://url/json.php',
                    params={"workspace_id" : "xyz", "since" : since, "until" : until},
                    auth= (_api_token, 'api_token'),
                    headers=headers)

dates = [
    {"since" : "2017-01-01", "until" : "2017-12-31"},
    {"since" : "2018-01-01", "until" : "2018-12-31"},
    {"since" : "2019-01-01", "until" : "2019-12-31"},
    {"since" : "2020-01-01", "until" : "2020-05-05"}
]

for date_pair_dict in dates:
    r = get_data(**date_pair_dict) # We can use dictionary->parameter expansion this way
                                   # which equals doing get_data(since=date_pair_dict['since'], ...)

    x = r.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(x['data'])
```

Now, because this is only partial code you've given.
We have no idea what you're actually using these data frames for in pandas. But you could put the `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` into your `get_data` function and then store and work on them later.

But this should hopefully give you an idea of how to create re-useable code, and how to deal with patterns in code and perhaps write code that can be re-used rather than copying it.

---

### Final note

Please post working code in the future, we spend a lot of time helping people. The last thing we need to do is help people to create a working example of the problem so we can then help people with their actual problem. We work for free and want to help, make it easier for us to help : )

Best of luck to your project.